# Print Message if HashMap name is Emply

Tags: java, hashmap

I have a program that when you type

> Circle name

in the Terminal, "name" goes into the HashMap then later I can type

> name visible

and the circle will appear on a canvas, or

> name invisible

and will then disappear. I'm using if else statement to call methods. I also created a statement called forget so When I type in

> name forget

it will remove "name" out of the HashMap then make the circle invisible if the circle is visible.

```
private void execute(String[] commands)
{

    String basicCommand = commands[0];
    Shape name = maps.get(commands[0]);
    if (commands.length >1) {
    if(basicCommand.equals("circle")) {
    //This Names the object Circle and Create a new Circle 
       maps.put(commands[1], new Circle());
    }
    else if(name != null && "visible".equals(commands[1])) {
        makeACircle(name);
    }
    else if(name != null && "forget".equals(commands[1])) {
        makeItInvisible(name);
        maps.remove(commands[0]);
    }
    else if(name != null && "invisible".equals(commands[1])) {
        makeItInvisible(name);
    }
    else if(basicCommand.equals("help")) {
        printHelp();
    }

        //This Should Print A Message if there is no Circle name 
        // in HashMap
    else if(commands[0] != null ) {
        System.out.println("Not In HashMap " + basicCommand);
    }
    else {
        System.out.println("Unknown command: " + basicCommand);
    }
}
```

}

If I use

> name forget

It will remove name from the HashMap

I need it to print a message when "name" is not in the HashMap if you type something "name visible", I need a message that print something like "not in HashMap" .

I tried it withing my if else statement, but anything below it does not work, and can't get it to work

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Searching a hashmap for a key is a pretty standard method for all languages including Java. Just call the following on your hashmap with your 'name' key.

public boolean containsKey(Object key)

more info here:

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/HashMap.html#containsKey(java.lang.Object)

Use this anytime a user requests a action to be done to an object they think is on the canvas. For your code:

```
if(!maps.containsKey(name))  {
    System.out.println("No object with name" + name);
}
```

Comment: anytime a user requests a action to be done to an object. (see answer)

Comment: This still does not work, when I type in > Circle name it prints out "No object with name"

And when I type lets say > name visible (where name was not added to the map) it does not give me any prints

Answer (score 2):

Looks like a typo error.  In your program it's wrote "circle" and you typed "Circle" with a upper-case letter.

Try equalsIgnoreCase instead of equals.